# QML: Formatting a number with varying precision and without exponent

Tags: qt, qml, number-formatting

In QML, I can format a number using [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-number.html#toLocaleString-method) (where my default locale is `en_US`); however, when given zero parameters, its behavior curiously isn't the same as what is documented, though it is almost what I want. The documentation states:

> If precision is not specified, the precision will be 2.

With zero parameters, the precision appears to vary depending on how precise the value is:

```js
console.log(123.0.toLocaleString()) // prints "123"
console.log(123.4.toLocaleString()) // prints "123.4"
console.log(123.45.toLocaleString()) // prints "123.45"
```

> If the format is not specified 'f' will be used.

With zero parameters, it behaves as if 'g' is the specified format, and uses exponential notation for large numbers:

```js
console.log(1000000.0.toLocaleString()) // prints 1e+06
```

---

While I would like to format the number with varying precision in my application, I would also like to disable the exponential format. However, if I pass any number of arguments to `toLocaleString`, the behavior changes to the documented default of 2 digits and a specifier of 'f':

```js
console.log(123.0.toLocaleString(Qt.locale())) // prints "123.00"
console.log(1000000.0.toLocaleString(Qt.locale())) // prints "1,000,000.00"
```

This effectively means I can't have *both* an 'f' format and varying precision, unless there is some undocumented special input for `precision` that preserves that behavior, or if I can somehow compute and pass the number of digits:

```js
x = 123.456
console.log(x.toLocaleString(Qt.locale(), 'f', decimals(x))) // should print "123.456"
```

Is there such an input, or is there some function `decimals` I can write to compute the number of significant digits after the decimal point?

I understand that floating-point is a binary format and doesn't precisely represent decimal digits / power-of-ten fractions, so it would be acceptable to take a few digits of precision away, instead treating 0.1000000009 or 0.0999999997 as 0.10000000. I'm using at most seven digits in my application, so I don't expect such an assumption to cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that performs successive multiplications up to the maximum desired precision, checking each digit and keeping track of the last non-zero digit seen.

```js
function decimals(x) {
  const maxDigits = 8;
  var remaining = x;
  var lastDigit = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= maxDigits; i++) {
    // Advance to next digit, cut off leading digits
    remaining = (remaining * 10) % 10

    // Round to account for *.99999 case, modulo 10 to account for 9.999
    if (Math.round(remaining) % 10 != 0) {
      lastDigit = i;
    }
  }
  return lastDigit;
}
```